# Execute BroadcastReceiver when app is killed Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I am doing an App that block some calls. I have a Broadcast Receiver to fix this. But when I kill my app (manually or by system), receiver doesn't work.

I have thought I need a service that execute a Broadcast Receiver, or block calls for itself. How can I do this?

Thank you for advantage.

EDIT
My receiver class:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ITelephony telephonyService;
    try {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);


        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");


                m.setAccessible(true);
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);


                if ((number != null)) {
                    telephonyService.endCall();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ending the call from: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Toast.makeText(context, "Ring " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Answered " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Idle " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Receiver manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ARQ.IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: did you add the receiver to your manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I have a receiver in my manifest. But when App is killed, doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide the code of your Receiver class?

Comment: Done, I hope you can see better.

Comment: on first look I would suggest to check if `intent.getStringExtra()` or `intent.getExtra()` return something?

Comment: But when my app is killed, when I call, nothing happens. Doesn't matter if intent have something no?

Comment: try to add `exported = true` in your broadcast receiver in manifest file

Comment: It's done. I will post the receiver for you. See.